# Get previous value based in specific item

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying a script where we use a list item and then I will get the previous item.

```
lst = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10]

next_item = next((x for x in lst if x > 6), None)
print next_item #8
```

This code works correctly for the item after 6. However i need the item before 6.

I am looking in docs for a prev method but i can't find anything related.
Any idea about that?

Comment: 1) Is `lst` always sorted? 2) Are you looking for the first element *larger*/*smaller* than 6 or the element to the right/left of 6?

Comment: Iterators don't have a `prev`, they're forward-only. However, you can always iterate over adjacent pairs (see the recipe in the itertools docs); when pair[1] matches, pair[0] is the previous element.

Comment: Also, you make want to look at turning your comparison around, then using takewhile; the last element in that iterator will be the one you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming by "before" you mean "previous in `lst`", it is not necessary to use such a complicated way. This

```
lst[lst.index(6) - 1]
```

will give

```
4
```

while this

```
lst[lst.index(6) + 1]
```

will give

```
8
```

Of course you should check for index out of bound errors.

Comment: Not sure what the question should do for duplicates.

Comment: He's looking for the first number *larger* than 6, not for the first appearance of 6.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over the reversed list with a reverse condition :

```
>>> next((i for i in lst[::-1] if i<6),None)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the first number larger than 6 in `lst`, this is one way to do it:

```
lst = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10]
lst2 =[]
for num in lst:
    if num > 6:
        lst2.append(num)
        lst2.sort()
print lst2[0]
```

The output is `8`